# Windows Task Scheduler don't show execution errors

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-task

I'm trying to make a powerscript that will run from time to time through the windows task scheduler.

My problem is that the task scheduler do not display the task as failed, even though my script do fail.

This is the event that i get:

```
Level   Date and Time   Event ID    Task Category   Operational Code    Correlation Id
Information 15.03.2016 22:53:06 102 Task completed  (2) f03232d8-4196-4425-88a9-722028f9700a    "Task Scheduler successfully finished ""{F03232D8-4196-4425-88A9-722028F9700A}"" instance of the ""\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\ScheduledJobs\My Scheduled Task"" task for user ""VEGAR-M4800\vegar""."
Information 15.03.2016 22:53:06 201 Action completed    (2) f03232d8-4196-4425-88a9-722028f9700a    "Task Scheduler successfully completed task ""\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\ScheduledJobs\My Scheduled Task"" , instance ""{F03232D8-4196-4425-88A9-722028F9700A}"" , action ""StartPowerShellJob"" with return code 0."
Information 15.03.2016 22:53:03 200 Action started  (1) f03232d8-4196-4425-88a9-722028f9700a    "Task Scheduler launched action ""StartPowerShellJob"" in instance ""{F03232D8-4196-4425-88A9-722028F9700A}"" of task ""\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\ScheduledJobs\My Scheduled Task""."
Information 15.03.2016 22:53:03 100 Task Started    (1) f03232d8-4196-4425-88a9-722028f9700a    "Task Scheduler started ""{F03232D8-4196-4425-88A9-722028F9700A}"" instance of the ""\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\ScheduledJobs\My Scheduled Task"" task for user ""VEGAR-M4800\vegar""."
Information 15.03.2016 22:53:03 129 Created Task Process    Info    00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000    "Task Scheduler launch task ""\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\ScheduledJobs\My Scheduled Task"" , instance ""powershell.exe""  with process ID 12780."
Information 15.03.2016 22:53:03 107 Task triggered on scheduler Info    f03232d8-4196-4425-88a9-722028f9700a    "Task Scheduler launched ""{F03232D8-4196-4425-88A9-722028F9700A}""  instance of task ""\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\ScheduledJobs\My Scheduled Task"" due to a time trigger condition."
```

The Result.xml shows another story:

```
    <Results_Error z:Assembly="0" z:Id="61" z:Type="System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[[System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord, System.Management.Automation, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]">
  <items xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Management.Automation" z:Assembly="0" z:Id="62" z:Type="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord, System.Management.Automation, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]">
    <_items z:Id="63" z:Size="4">
      <ErrorRecord z:Assembly="System.Management.Automation, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" z:Id="64" z:Type="System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RemotingErrorRecord">
        <CliXml xmlns="" z:Assembly="0" z:Id="65" z:Type="System.String">&lt;Objs Version=&quot;1.1.0.1&quot; xmlns=&quot;http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04&quot;&gt;

&lt;Obj RefId=&quot;0&quot;&gt;

&lt;ToString&gt;@{Exception=System.Management.Automation.RemoteException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\source\flis\'.; TargetObject=; FullyQualifiedErrorId=FileOpenFailure,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutFileCommand; InvocationInfo=; ErrorCategory_Category=1; ErrorCategory_Activity=Out-File; ErrorCategory_Reason=DirectoryNotFoundException; ErrorCategory_TargetName=; ErrorCategory_TargetType=; ErrorCategory_Message=OpenError: (:) [Out-File], DirectoryNotFoundException; SerializeExtendedInfo=False; ErrorDetails_ScriptStackTrace=at &amp;lt;ScriptBlock&amp;gt;, &amp;lt;No file&amp;gt;: line 1_x000D__x000A_at Do-Backup, &amp;lt;No file&amp;gt;: line 66_x000D__x000A_at &amp;lt;ScriptBlock&amp;gt;, &amp;lt;No file&amp;gt;: line 83}&lt;/ToString&gt;
....
</CliXml>
        <RemoteErrorRecord_OriginInfo xmlns="" z:Assembly="System.Management.Automation, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" z:Id="66" z:Type="System.Management.Automation.Remoting.OriginInfo">
          <_computerName xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Management.Automation.Remoting" z:Id="67">localhost</_computerName>
          <_instanceId xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Management.Automation.Remoting">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</_instanceId>
          <_runspaceID xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Management.Automation.Remoting">975a8cbe-dbd1-43c0-80b4-19c282eee381</_runspaceID>
        </RemoteErrorRecord_OriginInfo>
      </ErrorRecord>
      <ErrorRecord i:nil="true"/>
      <ErrorRecord i:nil="true"/>
      <ErrorRecord i:nil="true"/>
    </_items>
    <_size>1</_size>
    <_version>1</_version>
  </items>
</Results_Error>
```

I have created the task it self by invoking the following inside a scipt:

```
function Create-Task
{
    Param($name, $description)

    $trigger = New-JobTrigger -Daily -At 1am
    $options = New-ScheduledJobOption -WakeToRun -RequireNetwork

    Register-ScheduledJob -Name $name -FilePath $MyInvocation.PSCommandPath -ArgumentList "Run", $MyInvocation.PSScriptRoot -Trigger $trigger -ScheduledJobOption $options
}
```

Any idea why I don't get a nice red error ?

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell.exe does normally not return an error code even if the PowerShell script fails. Only if it's unable to load the PowerShell script will it return a non-zero error code.

I usually use the following command line to get my process to return a non-zero error code in case the script fails:

```
PowerShell.exe -Command "& {& 'C:\MyPowerShellScript.ps1' ; EXIT $LASTEXITCODE }"
```

If something inside the script fails the whole process will return a non-zero error level, and this can then be detected by the Task Scheduler.

Comment: I'm not able to add this to my Register-ScheduledJob, though..

Comment: I guess I have to use the `-ScriptBlock` parameter instead of the `-Path` parameter, but I'm not able to get all the quotes and stuff right...

Comment: There is general challenge in getting the error status out of a PS script, which I believed that my way of starting the script solved, but I have just done some testing, and it will only work in some cases, depending on how the script fails. So to test if the error get lost inside PS or is just not delivered correctly to the Task Scheduler, please try this statement inside your PS Script: `Exit(2)`. This should make your script exit with errorlevel 2 and you should then be able to see if this return code is correctly detected by Task Scheduler.

Comment: The return code is picked up partly... 
The history of the scheduled job shows an even `201 Action completed` with the text `Task Scheduler successfully completed task "..." , action "StartPowerShellJob" with return code 2147942402.` So it successfully completed the task, but the task returned an error code. So the problem is: How to make it say it failed when the task returns an error code?

Comment: I believe that `return code 2147942402` in the event log and History in Task Scheduler is the equivalent of Last Run Result = 2 in the Task Scheduler overview. I believe that the Task Scheduler does not consider this an error, since the PowerShell was started correctly, hence no error in the Event Log. I think you have to look into either logging to the event log or some other kind of error handling from your Script. You might want to look into a try/catch structure or trap.

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm starting to believe my self: It's not possible to have a scheduled task fail based on the outcome of the action. As long as the action was run, it's a success.